# Intuition behind the coordinate descent convergence

Tags: intuition, coordinate-descent

I am looking at the page 6 of the [slides](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/25-coord-desc.pdf) about Coordinate Descent of Geoff Gordon and Ryan Tibshirani at the Carnegie Mellon University.

They are dealing with the the Coordinate Descent algorithm convergence for the case of  $f(x)=g(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} h(x_i)$, where both $g$ and $h$ are convex and $h$ is a non-smooth separable function.

Edit: The missing assumption (as pointed by @whuber):
Given convex, differentiable $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, if we are at a point $x$ such that $f(x)$ is minimized along each coordinate axis, have we found a global minimizer?

What have I tried?

For all $y$:
 $$g(y)-g(x)\ge \nabla g(x)(y-x) \text{ [since $g$ is convex]}$$
 $$h(y)-h(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (h(y_i)-h(x_i))$$
 Therefore,
 $$f(y)-f(x)=g(y)-g(x)+h(y)-h(x)\ge$$ 
$$\nabla g(x)(y-x)+\sum_{i=1}^{n} (h(y_i)-h(x_i))=$$
 $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\nabla_i g(x)(y_i-x_i) +h(y_i)-h(x_i))\ge 0,$$

However, I do not understand the last inequality. I mean why 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\nabla_i g(x)(y_i-x_i) +h(y_i)-h(x_i))\ge 0?$$
I understand that $\nabla_i g(x)$ is positive due to the algorithm, but not the reason the entire expression is positive. It must be something obvious since there is no comment at the slide. What am I missing?

**Just to be clear, I am not looking for the full proof of convergence (that I can find in the paper). I would like to discover what I am missing in these slides.** Any help will be very wellcome!

Comment: Clearly the information you have provided does not assure the final inequality, because $y$ and $x$ play identical roles in the derivation and switching them reverses the inequality.  Evidently some implicit assumption has been made about $x$ and $y.$  The solution appears on slide 3: **$x$ is a point that minimizes the objective function separately in each coordinate direction.**  Please include this assumption in your post. (At that point the answer ought to be obvious.)

Comment: Yes, sure. Thank you! Now it is clear! Without this hypothesis is impossible to conclude anything.